# How to manipulate this type of timestamps with pandas?

Tags: pandas, time-series, timestamp, data-manipulation

I have a dataset that looks like this and I've been having a really hard time trying to figure out how to manipulate those types of timestamps, I don't even know if they have a name/type etc and I could use all the help I could get or insights.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/). Update: and as I have seen just yet, it's the Unixtime in milliseconds. I've updated my code.

You can convert it into a more readable format with `pd.to_datetime(dta["timestamp"], unit="s")`. But besides that there are advantages to have it in this format (easier to parse, less size and so on).

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime

now = int(time.time()) * 1000

dta = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp":now}, index=[0])

dta["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(dta["timestamp"], unit="ms")
```

**Output:**

```
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
|    |   timestamp     | datetime            |
|----+-----------------+---------------------|
|  0 |  16443491050000 | 2022-02-08 19:38:25 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! Do you think the "entry_time" column is a UNIX timestamp as well? I mean, should I create a new column out of it too?

Comment: Yes, this is the same format (also UNIX timestamp) :-)